# Passing Vectors to a Variadic Template

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a numeric method coded using Variadic templates. I want to pass a mixture of parameters to it, some of type double and some of type vector. Minimal example;

```
template<typename... Ts>
using custom_function_t = double(*) (double, Ts...);

template<typename... Ts> 
double BiPart(double min, double max,custom_function_t<Ts...> f,Ts... args)
double FunctionA(double A, double a, double b, vector<double> &C);
int main()
{
    double a=0, b=1,x=0, y=1;
    vector<double> C;
    BiPart(x,y,FunctionA, a,b, &C);
    return(0);
}

double FunctionA(double A, double a, double b, vector<double> &C)
{
some stuff here
}
```

I get the errors:
'no matching function for call to 'Bipart(...)''
'Template argument deducation/substitution failed: inconsistent parameter pack deducation with 'std::vector&' and 'std::vector''.

Comment: Are you quite sure that you're compiling *this* program? It has several typos and results in different compilation error than what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, the full error I get from gcc (when I remove the ampersand from in front of `C`) is:

```
balls.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
balls.cpp:15:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘BiPart(double&, double&, double (&)(double, double, double, std::vector<double>&), double&, double&, std::vector<double>&)’
     BiPart(x,y,FunctionA, a,b, C);
                              ^
balls.cpp:15:34: note: candidate is:
balls.cpp:9:8: note: template<class ... Ts> double BiPart(double, double, custom_function_t<Ts ...>, Ts ...)
 double BiPart(double min, double max,custom_function_t<Ts...> f,Ts... args);
        ^
balls.cpp:9:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
balls.cpp:15:34: note:   inconsistent parameter pack deduction with ‘std::vector<double>&’ and ‘std::vector<double>’
     BiPart(x,y,FunctionA, a,b, C);
                              ^
```

So it clearly says it's trying to match a `vector<double>&` with another `vector<double>&` but later in the error message forgets that it's dealing with a reference. Compiler bug maybe? Or just c++ being c++.

I know this doesn't answer your question but if you only want to borrow the vector from `BiPart` you can pass it as a `vector<double>*` (instead of a reference) and it will work. And if you want to move the data into the `BiPart` call without copying it you can make the function argument a `vector<double>&&` and then call BiPart with `move(C)`. That compiles too.

Comment: We have two different definitions of "clearly"... ;)

Comment: In this case I just need to get the data stored in the vector into BiPart for some calculations, I dont care about modifying it in BiPart so I'll use the vector<double>* option and test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably actually calling that function like this:

```
BiPart(x,y,FunctionA, a,b, C);
```

and not with a pointer to the vector as in your post, right?

If so, the error message is actually pretty descriptive. What happens is something like this: the last parameter you're passing in, `C`, is used in type deduction two times, once for the argument `f` and once for the argument `args`. In the first case, because of how `FunctionA` is declared, it's type is deduced as `std::vector<double>&`. In the second case it gets deduced as a simple `std::vector<double>`, no reference. Because in both places you have used the same template argument, `Ts...`, these have to match exactly.

To fix this you can tackle the problem from different angles:

You can modify `FunctionA` to take the last argument by value instead of by reference. This will fix it because this time both deduced types will match (both will be deduced as `std::vector<double>`).

You can also unlink the two deduced types so they don't have to match, by using different argument typenames for the two functions:

```
template<typename... Ts, typename... OtherTs> 
double BiPart(double min, double max, custom_function_t<Ts...> f, OtherTs&&... args);
```

Notice the two template arguments. In this case the types deduced for argument `f` (still `std::vector<double>&` for the last) don't have to match exactly the types deduced for the rest of the arguments for `BiPart` (`std::vector<double>` for the last).

Comment: You have to use `OtherTs&&... args`, else you still pass by copy.